# Cannot calculate total size of directory with my file program

Tags: java, file

I'm having a slight problem with what I just mentioned above.

For your reference, here is my code for this program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DirectorySizeProcessor extends DirectoryProcessor
{
    /*
    Dan Czarnecki
    October 17, 2013

    Class variables:
        private Vector<Long> directorySizeList
            Variable of type Vector<Long> that holds the total file size of files in that directory
            as well as files within folders of that directory

        private Vector<File> currentFile
            Variable of type Vector<File> that

    Modification History
        October 17, 2013
            Original version of class
            Implemented run() and processFile() methods
    */

    private Vector<Long> directorySizeList;
    private Vector<File> currentFile;

    public DirectorySizeProcessor(File startingDirectory) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        super(startingDirectory);
        directorySizeList = new Vector<Long>();
        currentFile = new Vector<File>();
    }

/*
    public void run()
    {
        File file;
        file = directoryLister.next();
        while(file != null) //the following will be called when the File object is not null
        {
            processFile(file);
            file = directoryLister.next();
        }
    }
*/


    public void processFile(File file)
    {
        Long hold;
        Long currentSize;
        Long finalTotal;
        int index;
        File parentFile;

        parentFile = file.getParentFile();
        index = this.currentFile.indexOf(parentFile);

        if(index < 0)
        {
            this.directorySizeList.addElement((long)0);
            this.currentFile.addElement(file.getParentFile());
        }
        while(index > 0)
        {
            currentSize = this.directorySizeList.get(index);
            hold = file.length();
            finalTotal = hold + currentSize;
            //System.out.println("current size: " + parentFile);
            //System.out.println("current size: " + currentSize);
            System.out.println("file: " + file);
            System.out.println("current size: " + file.length());
            parentFile = parentFile.getParentFile();
            index = this.getParentDirectory().indexOf(parentFile);
            finalTotal = file.length() + finalTotal;
            System.out.println("final total: " + finalTotal);
        }

    }

    public void run()
    {
        File file;
        file = directoryLister.next();


        while(file != null) //the following will be called when the File object is not null
        {
            processFile(file);
            file = directoryLister.next();
        }

    }

    public Vector getParentDirectory()
    {
        return this.currentFile;
    }

    public Vector getDirectorySizeList()
    {
        return this.directorySizeList;
    }


}
```

I know that the problem mainly lies within my processFile() method.  When I run it from my Driver class (via the run() method, which does call the processFile() method within it), it properly shows the sizes of each individual file (in bytes), but I don't think it's calculating the size of the entire directory as it's not matching up with the size that's being shown in a property window.  Could someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set the index after adding a new directory/size to the vectors, that probably causes it to always skip the first file of any directory.

```
    ...
    index = this.currentFile.indexOf(parentFile);

    if(index < 0)
    {
        this.directorySizeList.addElement((long)0);
        this.currentFile.addElement(file.getParentFile());
        // set the index again to make it enter the while loop
        index = this.currentFile.indexOf(parentFile);
    }
    while(index > 0)
    {
    ...
```